# Is there a way to specify attributes at a higher level in a chef .kitchen.yml file?

Tags: chef-infra

I have several suites I want to include in my .kitchen.yml file. Many of the attributes for each suite are largely the same. Is there a way to specify a default set of attributes or some other means to not having to cut/paste the attributes in several locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, put them under the provisioner section.

Comment: After looking through the documentation, I assume you mean "platforms" section, right?

Comment: Nope, I meant what I said :P